# Installing Windows Updates with a local Powershell Script on a remote computer without progress bar

Tags: powershell

I'm in the middle of installing Windows Updates remotely with Powershell.
The problem is that when I call on a server to run a local PS script that will install the updates, the progress on my local computer keeps on regenerating or popping up with no end.
[image]

Here's the code snippet I'm using to call on the server:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $All -Credential $Cred1 -ArgumentList $Text -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {
    & "C:\Users\$($args[0])\Documents\Powershell\WindowsUpdate\InstallWU.ps1" -ArgumentList "--quiet" -Verb runas
}
```

In the particular link above, this is the snippet that will do the installation process locally:

```
Get-WindowsUpdate -Install -AcceptAll -IgnoreReboot
```

I do believe that this may contribute to the multiple progress bars popping up.
How can I install Windows Updates from a remote computer without having the progress bar show up?
Will it be possible for the installation to be complete?

Comment: Is this from https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate/2.0.0.4 or is is from existing modules? `Get-Command -Module WindowsUpdate,WindowsUpdateProvider`

Comment: This is from Powershell 2.2.0.2. Get-WindowsUpdate -Install is an alias for Get-WUInstall.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here, because PSWindowsUpdate is a compiled dll, but what happens if you do `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` before calling `Get-WindowsUpdate` ?

Comment: I successfully managed to use that variable so it wouldn't bug out. But, for some reason, it still would not install.

Comment: When I went to the server with the local script, I went to see the log that kept on flashing the list of updates, again and again. I knew it wasn't installing or downloading, even when the progress was popping up over and over.